# Is there a breathing sensor for the Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, sensor

I'm searching for a small breath sensor that can be plugged in on Raspberry. Just detecting inhaling and exhaling, how many times you inhale per minute. Is there such thing?

I searched and searched and all I found was a spirometer and other equipemts you have to wear. I'm searching for sensors that work without touching the person, one meter away from the person at least, maybe a bit less than that.

Comment: This is *really* unlikely in any kind of cost effective way. What would you detect from a metre away? Temperature change is going to be effectively zero, audio's going to be too quiet, air pressure change is going to be zero.

Comment: I agree with @goobering. This would quickly become impractical with a Pi. From a meter away, detected CO2 is negligible, You may need a darn good infrared sensor or a full-blown infrared camera (and a PC at this point, Pi won't cut it). Human breath using an IR cam: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPMfv-CstN8

Comment: @PandaLion98 yes i need something like whats in the video

Comment: @goobering i expect to hear audio and to have some pressure, coz the test is on exhausted people and people breathing in extreme situations, my plan is to neglect normal breathing

Comment: 1 metre is substantially too far away to reliably detect any usable breath readings from a subject unless you have access to a large budget/nice toys. The cheapest usable FLIR sensor (similar to PandaLion98's IR cam) I can see comes in at $259 and wouldn't come close to sensitive enough for breath temps at 1m. I'm thinking there are many good reasons that spirometers affix to the face. The least obtrusive reliable methods I can think of are either audio from a headset mic, or resistance readings from a stretch sensor.

Comment: @goobering forget about the budget, my project will either be funded, in which case the budget is not a problem, unless we are talking about a huge number, or dead. It's not a personal project.So lets forget about the budget and focus on solutions. I'll try to make the budget look sexy when meeting with investors.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi really doesn't have the horse power to do what you want. You need a hugely powerful computer to pull this kind of stuff off.

Comment: @Lynob After what you said, you could pull it off using only a microphone provided that the room is really quiet and your mic is a bit more sensitive than normal (directional mic preferably). Then, whip something up on the Pi to recognize inhales or exhales or whatever you need to detect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an IR temp sensor array.
AMS makes IR temp array sensor or you can use MLX90620.
you can draw a graph of temp data near the nose area.
you will see temp peaks every time you exhale. 
but this sensor doesn't have 1m range.

Comment: Looking at [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzRj3y7ybF4) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVBe_q1ouJk) for these things doesn't inspire me with confidence. I'm not sure they've got either the refresh rate or resolution to deal with human breathing.